# Are ELF binaries with ABIs of 'System V' and 'Linux' mutually compatible?

Tags: c, linux, linker, cross-platform, elf

TL;DR : My binary is unable to load /lib64/libm.so, and I don't know why. Peering at the elves' fuzzy little headers, the only thing that looks like an incompatibility is the ABI number.

Long form:
Test run bombs claiming the binary is not found - but it exists.

```
[aardvark@aardvark-burrow ~/project-src] ldd  /data/users/aardvark/project-src/buck-out/gen/arvr/libraries/perception/calib/metrics/metrics_test
/data/users/aardvark/project-src/buck-out/gen/arvr/libraries/perception/calib/metrics/metrics_test: error while loading shared libraries: /lib64/libc.so: invalid ELF header
```

cat-ing /lib64/libm.so reveals:

```
/* GNU ld script
*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /lib64/libm.so.6  AS_NEEDED ( /usr/lib64/libmvec_nonshared.a /lib64/libmvec.so.1 ) )
```

Following the links to the bitter end, I get an ELF file. I read the header for that and for the binary which needs it, stuff 'em into text files, and diff those:

```
[aardvark@aardvark-burrow ~/project-src] diff ~/logs/elf.ray_transport_test.txt ~/logs/elf.libm.txt 
--- /home/aardvark/logs/elf.ray_transport_test.txt  2021-12-06 11:34:40.843179878 -0800
+++ /home/aardvark/logs/elf.libm.txt    2021-12-06 11:33:50.264101198 -0800
@@ -1,20 +1,20 @@
 ELF Header:
-  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
+  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
   Class:                             ELF64
   Data:                              2's complement, little endian
   Version:                           1 (current)
-  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
+  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - GNU 
   ABI Version:                       0
   Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
   Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
   Version:                           0x1
-  Entry point address:               0x13220
+  Entry point address:               0xc520
   Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
-  Start of section headers:          15936800 (bytes into file)
+  Start of section headers:          2189472 (bytes into file)
   Flags:                             0x0
   Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
   Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
   Number of program headers:         9
   Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
-  Number of section headers:         40
-  Section header string table index: 39
+  Number of section headers:         37
+  Section header string table index: 36
```

My VM id's itself through uname -a thus:

```
Linux aardvark-burrow.zoo.com 5.6.13-0_fbk17_hardened_5815_gc01d8dbd2635 #1 SMP Fri Jul 9 10:54:31 PDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is this why my executable is failing?

What else could be the problem?

Comment: Are you building for Hurd?  My libs say System V.

Comment: The binary is to run on x86_64 Android builds running on an emulator hosted on the machine that I 'unamed' above. The same VM is the build machine.

Answer (score -1):

Your error message refers to `/lib64/libc.so`, not `/lib64/libm.so`.

It looks like something is trying to load `libc.so` (and `libm.so`) *instead* of loading `libc.so.6` (and `libm.so.6`).

Since the `.so` files are *not* ELF (they are linker scripts), *of course* trying to load them fails.

Assuming that the load is happening because `readelf -d metrics_test | grep NEEDED | egrep 'lib(c|m)\.so$` is non-empty, the problem is that `metrics_test` is not linked correctly.

In particular, when `metrics_test` was linked, it picked up some non-linker-script version of `libc.so` and `libm.so`.

You can use `-Wl,-t` at link time to find out *which* `libc.so` and `libm.so` the linker picked up.